# Using ng-repeat on multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm making a weather application but I'm stuck on what should be a simple task but I can't wrap my head around how this works since I'm new to Angular. Basically what I need is to iterate over two arrays at once and set some values from this array.

In theory this is what I wanna accomplish:

```
<div ng-repeat="city in cities" ng-repeat="temp in temperatures" id={{city.id}}>
    <span>{{temp}}</span>
</div>
```

But obviously you can't put multiple repeaters like this. If I put an `ng-repeat` on the span I get 12 spans but I only need 1 and I need this 1 to contain the current value of the iteration in the `temperatures`.

The arrays looks like this after being created dynamically using an API:

Cities: `[object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object]`

Temperatures: `[-2.3, -0.2, -1.2, -25.4, 2.9, -4.8, -2.2, -12.1, 0.3, -5.9, -7.7, -0.1]`

How would I do this?

Comment: Why so You have The date in different objects. Combine your data into one json object. This saves You a lot of hassel.

Comment: @msohns I can't unfortunately that's why I'm struggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an index (assuming `temperatures` is the array of temperatures defined in the same controller):

```
<div ng-repeat="city in cities">
    <span>City: {{city}} - Temperature: {{temperatures[$index]}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be temperatures[$index] actually but that did it, thanks :) what exactly is the $index? Is that the current iteration value (1, 2, 3 etc) from cities loop?

Answer (score 3):

you cant use two `ng-repeat` in one div.

you need a alternative way of doing this, please try this suggestion

```
<div ng-repeat="city in cities" id={{city.id}}>
    <span>{{temperatures[$index]}}</span>
</div>
```

---- **for the best practice**

**don't use `$index`** its a bad practice but you can achieve what u want in this case.

you can do something like this,

```
<div ng-repeat="city in cities">
    <span>City: {{city}} - Temperature: {{ getTemprature(city) }}</span>
</div>
```

in controller,

```
$scope.getTemprature = function(city) {
    var index = cities.indexOf(city);
    return temperatures[index];
}
```

because if you use `orderBy` with the `ng-repeat` `$index` will not behave like u assume, `$index` will get the ordered array `$index` not the actual array `$index`.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with [lodash's `zip` function](https://lodash.com/docs#zip). Try this:

**Controller**

```
$scope.combinedData = _.zip(cities, temperatures);
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="row in combinedData" id="{{row[0].id}}">
    <span><b>{{row[0].name}}</b> {{row[1]}}</span>
</div>
```

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hojrhLx5/1/