# Passing value from html to AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using Angular Meteor and I have a controller that subscribes to a publish-composite publish which returns two cursors. What I am trying to do is to ng-repeat on one cursor and get value from the second cursor based on the value of the first one. Like this:

```
{{getName(a.id)}}
```

where a is one object of the first cursor, and in the controller I have `$scope.getName(id)` function that returns name from the second cursor, like this:

```
name = second.find({ID: id}).fetch()[0].name
```

it worked but the problem is the `getName` function gets hit for unnecessary number of times. Is there a better way to get data from the second cursor based on `ng-repeat` object of the first cursor? Is nested `ng-repeat` the way to do? How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "returns two cursors" mean?

Comment: Is there no way you can merge the two arrays if it's a 1-1 lookup after you get both "cursors" and ng-repeat over the flat data structure? In fact, if the indexes are the same, what about something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094394/using-ng-repeat-on-multiple-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you are focused on the performance of the `ng-repeat`. Glad you feel this way! From what I remember, the `ng-repeat` has been a focus of optimization across many 3rd party libraries and discussions.

In your case, my first attempt would be to bind the value inside the `ng-repeat` only once. You can do this using the `::` syntax on the expression.

For example, this would call the expression once.

```
<ul ng-repeat="a in items">
  <li>{{::getName(a.id)}}</li>
</ul>
```

At the end of your question you mentioned a nested repeat but your question only mentions a single use of it. Am I missing something?

Disclaimer: I've never used Angular Meteor (or even standalone Meteor) so there could very well be a better way do solve your problem.

via: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression